# minipage for columns has problems with itemize

Tags: beamer, itemize, minipage

I tried to make two columns in my `beamer` presentation, but apparently there is an issue with `itemize`. The the columns don't start at the same height for some reason I don't understand.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[%
  hyperref={colorlinks=true,urlcolor=blue},%
  t,%
  aspectratio=169%
]{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Introduction}
 \fbox{\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}
  \begin{itemize}
   \item hallo  
  \end{itemize}
 \end{minipage}}%
 \fbox{\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}
  hallo
 \end{minipage}}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

and the result

[image]

So the question is how can I force them the start at the same height?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick fix; use the `T` option for the `minipage` instead.

```
\documentclass[%
  hyperref={colorlinks=true,urlcolor=blue},%
  t,%
  aspectratio=169%
]{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Introduction}
 \fbox{\begin{minipage}[T]{.5\textwidth}
  \begin{itemize}
   \item hallo  
  \end{itemize}
 \end{minipage}}%
 \fbox{\begin{minipage}[T]{.5\textwidth}
  hallo
 \end{minipage}}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

**Edit:**

And the beamer solution is using `columns`:

```
\documentclass[%
  hyperref={colorlinks=true,urlcolor=blue},%
  t,%
  aspectratio=169%
]{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Introduction}

\begin{columns}
\begin{column}[T]{0.5\textwidth}
\fbox{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}%
  \begin{itemize}
   \item hallo
   \item hallo  
  \end{itemize}
\end{minipage}}%
\end{column}
\begin{column}[T]{0.5\textwidth}
\fbox{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
  hallo
\end{minipage}}
\end{column}
\end{columns}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: okay the capital T is the solution. However, now If the boxes don't have the same height they again don't start at the same position :(

Comment: I've added another solution using beamer's `columns`.

Answer (score 2):

with `tabularx` and small manual tweak?

```
\documentclass[ hyperref={colorlinks=true,urlcolor=blue},%
                t,%
                aspectratio=169%
]{beamer}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\compress}{\@minipagetrue}
\makeatother
\newcolumntype{I}{ >{\compress\itemize}X<{\enditemize}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Introduction}
 \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|I|X|}
 \hline
   \item hallo
   \item hallo
 &  \vspace*{-2pt}
  hallo    \\
  \hline
 \end{tabularx}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]